# Print CSS, Bootstrap & PHP

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

This is semi related to my last question but i have set up a filemaker foreach loop to output a group of images to accompany there names and ids, along with a checkbox.

Once checked the relating images go to another page to print, No matter how much i try i cant get the elements to fit to one page ?
I have used inline styling, a Print css stylesheet, all possible combinations with chromes inspector.

I can make it fit, once the image name is taken away, but i need this included.

```
include('head.php');
if (isset($_POST['img'])) {

$img = $_POST['img'];

} else {
$img = '';
echo 'error';
}

?>
<div class="container">
<div class="row" >
<?

foreach ($img as $image){

//echo '<div class="col-md-5">';
echo '<img class="" style="margin:20px 10px 10px 0px; width:45%;" src="Invoices/Photos/RC_Data_FMS/Invoices_db/Photos/'.$image.'">';
echo '<p class="centered" style="width:45%;">'.$image.'</p>';
//echo '</div>';

} 
?>
</div>
</div>
```

Basically i'm trying to achieve an A4 portrait, with a grid of 6 images, with a margin between and the label underneath.

I tried pushing everything into a `col-md-6` div, taking the `<p>` tags away but this didn't help.

I also tried using px opposed to %, just cant figure this one out.

The code from the previous page;

```
echo '<input type="checkbox" class="form-control check" id="img" name="img[]" value="'.$pic.'">';
```

With the $pic variable being the image name.

Comment: you say you want a grid of 6 images... is that 3 tall by 2 wide?

Comment: I think this really comes down to how TALL your images are, not how wide. You can tweak their height with an @media print style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can achieve what you want by tweaking the img height in `@media print`, like so:

```
@media print{
  img{max-height:280px} //tweak this until you're happy

}
```

Also, don't forget the `img-responsive` bootstrap class - it works wonders:)

```
<div class="col-xs-6"> <!-- this will limit img width if img-responsive used too-->
  <img class="img-responsive" src="image.jpg">
  <p>Filename 1</p>
</div>
```

You can probably also forgo most of your inline styling and stick with bootstrap's defaults at first, then tweak later if you really need to.

http://www.bootply.com/YZkHOq0C1i

Comment: Worked a treat, id been trying to manipulate them by there width to fit the page but the height instantly sorted the problem, Thank you ! : )